Preventing the Gibbs phenomenon on a reverse FFT
i am currently filtering some data and ran into trouble, when filtering smaller frequencies from a large trend.The Reverse FFTs seem to have large spikes at the beginning and the ending. Here is the Data before and after filtering smaller frequencies.
I have looked into the mathematic phenomenon and it is called the Gibbs phenomenon. Is there a way around this to clear the data of some overlying frequencies without getting this effect. Or is there even a workaround to keep the spikes as small as possible.
Here is the code BTW:
fourier_transformation= np.fft.fft(Sensor_4)
frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(len(time), d=1/Values_per_second) 
fourier_transformation[np.abs(frequencies) > 0.18] = 0
Sensor_4 = np.fft.ifft(fourier_transformation)


That's not how filtering is done at all.  You should really start with a google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=digital+filtering

@MattTimmermans How would you filter the signal, then?

You can do it this way if you must and it can be made to work - especially for a single spot frequency. Your problem is that the FFT has implicit translational boundary conditions so that your high end of the graph is right next to the low value at the start. That discontinuity is driving the Gibb's phenomena. Simplest quick fix is subtract a ramp function or maybe a quadratic from the raw data so that it is continuous across the origin. Your brick wall filter is extremely brutal and many better filters exist with nicer properties. Search for digital filtering will help you. PS Look at the FFT

@simon that is right, fixed it

Following the suggestion of Martin Brown's comment, the following code subtracts a ramp before FFT and adds it back after IFFT (I needed to make up my own values for Sensor_4, Values_per_second, and time, as the corresponding variables were missing in the question, so you might need to tune the parameters to match your actual signal):
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create signal of Sensor_4 (similar to question)
T = 600
Values_per_second = 100  # Just to have a value here
time = np.arange(0, T, 1/Values_per_second)
Sensor_4 = 2 * np.sin(.25 * (2 * np.pi * time / T)) - 2.25
Sensor_4 += .1 * np.sin(1.9 * (2 * np.pi * time / T))
Sensor_4 += .1 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * time * 0.18)

frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(len(time), d=1/Values_per_second) 

# Original version
fourier_transformation = np.fft.fft(Sensor_4)
fourier_transformation[np.abs(frequencies) > 0.18] = 0
filtered_no_ramp = np.real(np.fft.ifft(fourier_transformation))

# Using ramp, as suggested in
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78788533#comment138912162_78788533
# (1) Create ramp, (2) subtract ramp, (3) FFT, (4) filter, (5) IFFT, (6) add ramp back
ramp = np.linspace(Sensor_4[0], Sensor_4[-1], len(Sensor_4))  # (1)
fourier_transformation = np.fft.fft(Sensor_4 - ramp)  # (2, 3)
fourier_transformation[np.abs(frequencies) > 0.18] = 0  # (4)
filtered_ramp = np.real(np.fft.ifft(fourier_transformation)) + ramp  # (5, 6)

# Show result
ax1 = plt.subplot(311, title="unfiltered")
plt.plot(time, Sensor_4)
plt.subplot(312, sharey=ax1, title="w/o ramp")
plt.plot(time, filtered_no_ramp)
plt.subplot(313, sharey=ax1, title="with ramp")
plt.plot(time, filtered_ramp)
plt.show()

Here is the result, before filtering (top), filtering without (center) and with (bottom) ramp subtraction:

